# JavaFX - setText does not work

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, settext

Iam creating an admin page that can change his/her password. My code so far is this:

```
@FXML
public void changePasswordButton(ActionEvent e) throws IOException, SQLException {
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycredentials?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", username, password);
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT pass FROM managerinfo WHERE pass = '"+oldpasswordBox.getText()+"'");

        ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(oldpasswordBox.getText()));
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        if(oldpasswordBox.getText().equals("")) {
            oldpasswordLabel.setText("Please enter your old password.");
        }
        else {
            if(result.next()) {
                if (newPasswordBox.getText().equals("")) {
                    enterNewPassword.setText("Please enter your new password.");
                }
                else {
                    if(newPasswordBox.getText().equals(verifyNewPasswordBox.getText())) {
                        Statement s = (Statement) connection.createStatement();

                        String sql = "UPDATE managerinfo SET pass = '"+ newPasswordBox.getText()+"' WHERE user = 'admin'";
                        s.executeUpdate(sql);
                        passwordChanged.setText("Password Changed.");
                    } 
                    else {
                        didNotMatched.setText("New password did not matched.");
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                oldPasswordNotMached.setText("Old password did not matched.");
            }

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My setText label wont work when i run the code. What will i do? Is this a wrong logic?

Comment: You shouldn't run database queries on the UI thread. Apart from that there is not enough information to reproduce the error. Also you could improve the question quality by identifying either the database or the ui as source of the error and removing the other part from the question.

Comment: What are the types of all these fields? Why are there so many different fields?